# $\operatorname{Ann}(\operatorname{Ann}(N))=N$ for a submodule $N$ of an $R$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals

Suppose $R$ is a commutative and unitary ring and $M$ is an $R$-module. Is it generally true that for any submodule $N$ in $M$, $\operatorname{Ann}(\operatorname{Ann}(N))=N$? 
If it's not true in general, then under what conditions can we prove it?

Comment: By definition, $\operatorname{Ann}$ yields an ideal of $R$. So if $N$ is not an ideal of $R$, $\operatorname{Ann}(\operatorname{Ann}(N))$ cannot equal $N$.

Comment: @azimut: although $\text{Ann}(N)$ is an $R$-ideal, $\text{Ann}(\text{Ann}(N))$ can refer to $0 :_M \text{Ann}(N)$, which is a submodule of $M$.

Comment: @user115654: Thanks. This is what I guessed. In my opinion, it should be made clear in the question that the two $\operatorname{Ann}$s are not the same.

Comment: **17 questions, no accepted answer!!!** Why? (Meanwhile, let me withdraw my answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smallest counterexample is given by the local $8$-element ring
$$R = \Bbb F_2[x,y]/(x^2,y^2,xy).$$

Its proper ideals are $(x) = \{0,x\}$, $(y) = \{0,y\}$, $(x+y) = \{0,x+y\}$ and the maximal ideal $(x,y) = \{0,x,y,x+y\}$ which is the nilradical of $R$.

Now consider
$$N = (x).$$
It's straightforward to check that
$$\operatorname{Ann}(N) = (x,y)$$
and
$$\operatorname{Ann}(\operatorname{Ann}(N)) = (x,y) \neq N.$$